# Angular CLI 'tsc' command is not copying index.html, nodemodules, css, etc in the dist folder

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli, angular2-template

I have Angular2 project created with CLI, the project is completed and I wanted to make all the *.js files, *js.map files, index.html/index.jsp, all the depending css, etc copied in the dist folder with proper architecture.

Currently, if I invoked 'tsc' command, all the *.js and *js.map files are copied to dist but nodemodules folder, index.html/jsp and css files are not copied.

I want these files to be copied there to deploy the dist content on server as browser only understand js and not the ts files.

**tsconfig**:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "query-builder",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^2.3.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jQuery-QueryBuilder": "^2.4.4",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "primeng": "^4.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

**angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "query-builder"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/css/query-builder.default.css",
        "../node_modules/jQuery-QueryBuilder/doc/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../src/app/selectizeFiles/selectize.bootstrap3.css",
        "../src/app/selectizeFiles/selectize.bootstrap2.css",
        "../src/app/selectizeFiles/selectize.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js",
        "../src/app/selectizeFiles/selectize.js",
        "../src/app/selectizeFiles/selectize.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "class": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

How can I make all the files copied to dist so as to deploy it directly on server?

Answer (score 2):

With angular-cli you should be using the built in `ng build` command. This does all the compiling & bundling, and will output all the proper files to your dist directory.

It also has an option to build source maps `ng build --sourcemaps=true`

I would read through all the options in their documentation 
 to determine your exact needs(https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)